# Poisson equation fast solver on large grids

Tags: computational-physics, c, poisson, conjugate-gradient

Below is kind of a broad question.

Was given Poisson equation with BC, on meshgrid of NxM.

Rewrote as system of N*M linear equations,

Converted to sparse format (CSR/CRS/Yale), solved using [Conj Grad method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method)

As for 100x100 grid computation time is ~0.3s and
if I increase the grid to 500x500, code runs for 11 seconds already.

Was initially looking for something fast that can be used as a subroutine for Navier-Stokes solver, i.e. will run the Poisson solver a big number of times.

Question - what is the optimal computation time and how to chose the grid size properly. Or, perhaps, shall I change the method completely, or maybe something wrong with it?

Below posted my conj function for CSR input format:

```
double *cj(double *val, int *col, int *row, int valSize, int colSize, int rowSize, double *b, int ansSize){
    double *x; 
    x = (double *) malloc(ansSize * sizeof(double));
    double *r;
    r = (double *) malloc(ansSize * sizeof(double));
    double *p;
    p = (double *) malloc(ansSize * sizeof(double));
    double *Ap;
    Ap = (double *) malloc(ansSize * sizeof(double));
    double rsold, alpha, rsnew, sum;
    int colStart = 0;
    int i, j, l, k, rowStart, rowEnd, colEnd;
    for (i = 0; i < ansSize; i++){// fill x with 0
        x[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ansSize; i++){
        rowStart = row[i];
        rowEnd = row[i+1];
        sum = 0;
        for (j = rowStart; j < rowEnd; j++){
            k = col[j];
            sum = sum + val[j]*x[k];
        }
        r[i] = b[i] - sum;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ansSize; i++){
        p[i] = r[i];
    }
    rsold = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ansSize; i++){
        rsold = rsold + r[i] * r[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ansSize; i++){
        for (l = 0; l < ansSize; l++){
            rowStart = row[l];
            rowEnd = row[l+1];
            sum = 0;
            for (j = rowStart; j < rowEnd; j++){
                k = col[j];
                sum = sum + val[j]*p[k];
            }
            Ap[l] = sum;
        }
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < ansSize; j++){
            sum = sum + p[j] * Ap[j];
        }
        alpha = rsold / sum;
        for (j = 0; j < ansSize; j++){
            x[j] = x[j] + alpha * p[j];
        }
        for (j = 0; j < ansSize; j++){
            r[j] = r[j] - alpha * Ap[j];
        }
        rsnew = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < ansSize; j++){
            rsnew = rsnew + r[j] * r[j];
        }
        if (sqrt(rsnew) < epsilon){
            return x;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < ansSize; j++){
            p[j] = r[j] + (rsnew/rsold)  * p[j];
        }
        rsold = rsnew;
    }
    free(r);
    free(p);
    free(Ap);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: If you are really doing just a square, I've witnessed nested dissection (https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/flame/laff/alaff/chapter07-reducing-fillin.html) being used to solve huge systems, think tens of millions of DOFs. However, I don't know the details. There is also something known as geometric multigrid which might help you out.

Comment: On a regular mesh, you can't beat multigrid in terms of speed, and given the structuredness of the mesh, it will even not be terribly difficult to implement.